# How to remove an unknown enum key on Jackson deserialization?

Tags: java, json, object, jackson, deserialization

I have a `Map<Alert, Boolean>` Map which is populated with the corresponding JSON:

```
{
   "BUTTON": true,
   "UNKNOWN": false
}
```

I have found that I can configure Jackson with DeserializationFeature.READ_UNKNOWN_ENUM_VALUES_AS_NULL to true to replace by null an unknown enum (here "UNKNOWN").

How can I just ignore the UNKNOWN enum and not put null in my Map ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `null` entry immediately after deserialization:

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper()
    .enable(DeserializationFeature.READ_UNKNOWN_ENUM_VALUES_AS_NULL);

Map<Alert, Boolean> map = om.readValue(json, new TypeReference<HashMap<Alert, Boolean>>() {});
map.remove(null);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I want it to be automatic if possible.

Comment: All right. Perhaps create your own `Map` class that ignores attemps to add entries with a `null` key?

Answer (score -1):

Keep it simple and execute the following line after Jackson finishes de-serialisation using the approach you've described:

```
map.remove("UNKNOWN");
```

No matter how many unknown enums your JSON document contains, you will always end up with a single 'UNKNOWN' key in the map.

> I'm sorry but I muddied the waters a bit with my initial answer by referring to 'UNKNOWN' as a map key. Unfortunately, I didn't get a chance to correct my post before @Henrik posted their answer until now. So, the correct removal of the redundant map key should be indeed:
>
> `map.remove(null)`
>
> **BTW. I'm not claiming any credit for this correction but only putting the record straight.**

Looking into other options, there doesn't seem to be a de-serialisation property available to satisfy your needs. Although you could implement your own JsonDeserializer, you would need to parse the whole JSON document and construct the map on your own.